# SQL Query Not Exist Performance Issue on Large Set of Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I had the following table structure which is listed below

Table Name : MachineLog (** 979478 Records**)

```
Companyid  DeviceEnrollNo  Employeeid  InOutDate    InOutTime   
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    12       ABC002          1         2018-10-06   18:08
    12       ABC003          2         2018-10-06   09:38
    12       ABC004          3         2018-10-06   08:25
    12       ABC005          4         2018-10-06   09:26
    12       ABC005          4         2018-10-06   10:19
    12       ABC006          5         2018-10-06   10:02
```

Table Name : Employee Detail (** 798 Records**)

```
    Id    Category     Companyid  Category      
    ---------------------------------------
    1        ABC002          12   15 
    2        ABC003          12   15 
    3        ABC004          12   17 
    4        ABC005          12   15 
    5        ABC006          12   26
```

Table Name : TimeEntry  (** 73398 Records**)

```
Companyid   Employeeid  EntryDate   EntryMethod 
    ----------------------------------------------
    12        1            2018-10-06   M
    12        2            2018-10-06   M
    12        3            2018-10-06   A
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Companyid  Employeeid  InOutDate    InOutTime   
    --------------------------------------------------------      
    12       3         2018-10-06   08:25
    12       4         2018-10-06   09:26
    12       4         2018-10-06   10:19
```

Question :

Basically, I want to fetch all the records from MachineLog table within given Date range Except those records which are Marked as 'M' in Time Entry table

But the Problem is Query which I had written takes a lot of time to execute around 10-15 min

**I'm Getting proper output but performance is very slow**

**How can i improve the performance of below query**

Query :

```
SELECT [t0].[CompanyId],
       [t0].[EmployeeId],
       [t0].[InOutDate],
       [t0].[InOutTime]
FROM [SCHEMA].[MachineLog] AS [t0]
JOIN [SCHEMA].[EmployeeDetail] AS [B] ON [t0].[EmployeeId] = [B].[Id]
WHERE (B.Category IN(15,17))
  AND ([t0].[CompanyId] = 12)
  AND ([t0].[InOutDate] >= '2018-09-30')
  AND ([t0].[InOutDate] <= '2018-10-20')
  AND (NOT (EXISTS
              (SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
               FROM [SCHEMA].[Entry] AS [t1]
               WHERE ([t1].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[EmployeeId])
                 AND ([t1].[CompanyId] = 12)                    
                 AND (([t0].[InOutDate]) = [t1].[EntryDate])
                 AND ([t1].[EntryMethod] = 'M') )))
ORDER BY [t0].[EmployeeId],
         [t0].[InOutDate]
```

Comment: Query plans please, plus indices. If you ahve hte indieces - bad luck. Better server, precalculated tables are standard solutions for reporitng style queries (keyword: data warehouse).

Comment: Use CTRL-L to observe the query plan and look for table scans, exclamation marks and suggested indexes. Since you haven't posted any indexes I guess you may not have done any investigation down that path

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i will check the query execution plan, i have not yet checked that

Comment: put an index on Entry, Employeeid,companyid, inoutdate,entrymethod - you've also got a duplicate condition on [t0].[EmployeeId] = [t1].[EmployeeId]

Comment: @Cato removed duplicate codition

Comment: did you try an index?  The duplicate condition would only be a factor if it somehow confuses optimisation

Comment: @Cato An index on entrymethod is useless. The table is super small, and this field seems to have only 2 possible values, making it a very poor candidate for indexing.

Comment: @Patrick Honorez - where did he tell us that?  he mentioned a table with 73398 records, for any employee he'd still have to look up the appropriate records in it to see if any has an M

Comment: A Clustered index on the InOutDate field of MachineLog table would definitely help and also a clustered index on the EntryDate of TimeEntry table

Comment: Let me throw another suggestion in here: a filtered index on `[EntryMethod] = 'M'` on table `Entry` on all join columns. But right now we're all taking guesses - he might have all these indexes or he might be running it on a 2Gb laptop

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Indexes was not present after adding index performance improved and getting result in 7-12 second now

Comment: Glad you sorted it.

Comment: @Cato I understand the M and A mean Manual or Automatic. An index on a field with few distinct values has very little efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of Execution plan, let me guess that the issue is not in your SQL statement, but rather in the indexes of your tables.

- does each table have a Primary Key, with a unique clustered index ?
- did you properly define and index your Foreign Keys ?
- the largest table with a filter applied is MachineLog.InOutDate. Is that field indexed ?

Once these are properly set, your query will probably fly.

---

On another point, I am curious about this `NOT (EXISTS (SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]`.
I would have written `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM...`
Any reason to `SELECT NULL` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem through temporary tables.

- create temporary table t1, like this:

  ```
  `insert into t1  (SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
  FROM [SCHEMA].[Entry] AS [t1]
  WHERE ([t1].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[EmployeeId])
  AND ([t1].[CompanyId] = 11)
  AND ([t0].[EmployeeId] = [t1].[EmployeeId])
  AND (([t0].[InOutDate]) = [t1].[EntryDate])
  AND ([t1].[EntryMethod] = 'M') `
  ```
- main table left join t1 to exclude data:

  ```
  `select * from m left join t1 on t1.id = m.id  where m1.id is  null`
  ```

Comment: That’s a bold statement

Answer (score 0):

this is untested but potentially could save time. instead of having the exists in the where clause you potentially reverse the logic and have it in the join.

```
SELECT 
    [t0].[CompanyId],
    [t0].[EmployeeId],
    [t0].[InOutDate],
    [t0].[InOutTime]
FROM 
    [SCHEMA].[MachineLog] AS [t0]
    JOIN [SCHEMA].[EmployeeDetail] AS [B] ON [t0].[EmployeeId] = [B].[Id]
    JOIN (SELECT [EmployeeId],[CompanyId],[EntryDate],[EntryMethod], COUNT(*) AS [DummyCount]
          FROM [SCHEMA].[Entry]  
          GROUP BY [EmployeeId],[CompanyId],[EntryDate],[EntryMethod]) AS [t1] 
        ON ([t1].[EmployeeId] = [t0].[EmployeeId] 
            AND [t1].[CompanyId] = [t0].[CompanyId]             
            AND [t1].[EntryDate] = [t0].[InOutDate] 
            AND [t1].[EntryMethod] != 'M')  
WHERE 
    (B.Category IN(15,17))
    AND ([t0].[CompanyId] = 11)
    AND ([t0].[InOutDate] >= '2018-09-30')
    AND ([t0].[InOutDate] <= '2018-10-20')
ORDER BY 
    [t0].[EmployeeId],
    [t0].[InOutDate]
```

Comment: Note that the join on the entry table is checking where 'EntryMethod' is not equal to 'M'

Comment: Unless there are many matching records in `Entry` in which case it will double count.

Comment: sheet, you are right. then you can do some dummy aggregation on the entry table. let me edit this.

Comment: For a performance question, I suggest at least waiting for index and query plan definition before suggesting a rewrite. Note that pre-aggregrating this is doing _more_ work and is unlikely to perform better.